# how to create space between string variables in a print statement by using Python

Tags: python, variables, string-concatenation

I want to create a user input that looks like this:

Enter your first name: Michael

Enter your last name: Sun

Enter your country: Canada

I am Michael Sun from Canada

Code below:

```
firstName = input(Enter your first name: )
lastName = input(Enter your last name: )
country = input(Enter your country: )
print("I am " + firstName + lastName + " from " + country)
```

My answer: I am MichaelSun from Canada

Question: How to create the space between my name?

Comment: `print("I am " + firstName + " " + lastName + " from " + country)`

Comment: Or use `join` -> `' '.join([firstName, lastName])`

Answer (score 1):

use fstrings if you are on python3.6 or above

```
print(f"I'm {firstname} {lastname}, from {country}")
```

also take a look at [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/), for many more ways to format.

Answer (score 0):

Adithya's answer works fine for doing it by hand, but the `print` function actually does this for you: it can take multiple positional parameters, and will print them with the value of `sep` inbetween. By default, `sep` is a single space character.

So you can just pass each item individually instead of concatenating them yourself:

```py
>>> print("I am", firstName, lastName, "from", country)
I am lazy man from lazytown
```

That aside, Python's standard naming conventions are `snake_case` for functions, methods, and local variables.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add a space between firstName and lastName

```
print("I am " + firstName + " " + lastName + " from " + country)
```